# An error occurred when ejecting 'DVD RW DRIVE'

Tags: dvd-burning, cd-burning

Good Afternoon!

Got a real headscratcher here. Windows 10 System on 1903, the client wanted me to install a DVD burner for replication purposes. Put it in, now neither the drive I installed or the old drive will 'eject' using the button inside the operating system.

They will both eject fine using the physical button. They will not format media for burning (when blank cd is inserted) but they read media just like they should.

I have removed both devices and let Windows handle the drivers and I run into the same problem.

I am stumped... the client purchased the drive for archiving purposes but without the ability to format the point is mute.

Anyone got any ideas?